# Laravel: forms and radiobuttons

Tags: php, html, laravel

I am just wondering if i could ask a fairly simple question about radio buttons and Laravel as the googlebox isnt co-operating. My code is thus:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url'=>'users/create', 'method' => 'post')) }}
    <tbody>
    <label><span>&nbsp;</span>{{ Form::submit('Approve/Decline')}}</label>
    @foreach($users as $user)
        <tr>
            <td>{{{$user->firstname}}}</a></td>
            <td>{{{$user->secondname}}}</a></td>
            <td>{{{$user->address}}}</a></td>
            <td>{{{$user->city}}}</a></td>
            <td>{{{$user->phone}}}</a></td>
            <td>{{{$user->id}}}</td>
            <td>{{{$user->username}}}</a></td>
            <td>{{{$user->email}}}</tds>
            <td>{{{$user->type}}}</a></td>
            <td>{{Form::radio('Membership[]', 'approve')}}</a></td>
            <td>{{Form::radio('Membership[]', 'decline')}}</a></td>

        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>


{{ Form::close() }}
```

A simple form with my two text boxes at the end there. This turns on fine in the browser but once i check one radio button the others deselect which would be fine in this order:

> O O

but since its in a loop, there are many rows of O O and i can only choose one out of all of the different rows. I would imagine I would need to group each two together somehow dynamically but I'm unsure. All aid appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to use *radio* buttons, or *checkboxes*? They are two completely different HTML elements with two different functions. You keep saying checkboxes, but you're generating radio buttons.

Comment: sorry about the confusion there, yes radio buttons is what I'm after. Iv edited to reflect; I am using them as I'v read they are more suited to the 'one select, the other deselects' implementation I am going for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you'll need to set a different name for each of your checkboxes/radio buttons:

```
<td>{{Form::radio("Membership[".$user->id."]", 'approve')}}</a></td>
<td>{{Form::radio("Membership[".$user->id."]", 'decline')}}</a></td>
```

To get your values in your controller you just have to:

```
dd( Input::get('Membership')[$user->id] );
```

In return you should get

```
approve
```

or

```
decline
```

Note that for this to work this way I removed the quotes from

```
"Membership[".$user->id."]"
```

Here are two routes I used to test it:

The form:

```
Route::any('test', function() {
    return Form::open(array('url' => 'radio', 'method' => 'post')) .
    Form::radio("Membership[1]", 'approve') .
    Form::radio("Membership[1]", 'decline') .
    Form::submit('send') .
    Form::close();
});
```

The result:

```
Route::any('radio', function() {
    dd( Input::get('Membership')[1] );
});
```

Comment: Antonio You are the Laravel man of mystery, This is the second time in a week you have solved my problems :) Thank you. But if i may be cheeky and ask one last sneaky question though, what is the best way for me to get that information out individually in my controller? As in, how do I then access the Membership array?

Comment: No problem. Edited to provide an answer for that too.

Comment: It seems to be having trouble with the [1] element of the controller bit, is this something you have encountered?